Changing the value of a cell (Text) based on the color of another cell
I work for a med group and on our intakes they ask if people are interested in our other services. I have columns with colors based on if that is a service they are interested in. I have an additional column that has those services listed out. What I would like is a formula that will automatically list out the services that person is interested in instead of having to manually type the list out. I already know how to find the color code for each color so for example: Cell Q3 has the color code of 20, Cell R3 has the color code of 40, cell S3 has the color code of 24. Color 20 stands for Family Medicine (FM), Color 40 stands for Behavioral Health (BH), Color 24 stands for Chiropractic (Chiro). In Column Z I would like those listed out based on the colors applied to Q3,R3, and S3 respectably. In this instance Column Z would AutoPopulate FM, BH, Chiro
If there was not a color in Q3 it would just say BH, Chiro. I am not finding anything to help me with this endeavor. Is there a way to do this or is there a way to kind of reverse this so that if I type in Column Z  "FM, BH, Chiro" it would automatically fill in the colors of the 3 corresponding cells?
I have tried If formulas and Get.Cell formulas but am not having luck.
I was going to just go the route of doing this =(AC183&"  "&AD183&"  "&AE183&"  "&AF183&"  "&AG183&"  "&AH183&" "&AI183&" "&AJ183&"") and then an additional Should return formula but the amount of formulas I would need is astronomical.

It sounds like you want conditional formatting to format the three cells based on a selection. That's on the Home tab on the ribbon. It takes some effort to understand how to set it up. YouTube is helpful for this.

I think checking the colour of a cell and returning text in another is possible with VBA, but the other way around is eassier with Contional formatting like bugdrown already said. If you can't figure it out, let us know (make an edit and reply to the comment), let us know what you did and we'll try to help.

Okay so I think you are all on the right track, however, I think it needs to be an IF formula but I can't quite figure out what it would be. Example would be I need for RANGE of A1:A1500 to be formated a certain color IF J1:J1500 contains "BH" ... it might contain other text as well though per my original post, the cell J1:J1500 might say "FM, BH, Chiro"

I found something KIND of like I want but it still isn't right -  =IF(contains(J1:J1500,"BH", TRUE),"Found,"Not found")

Okay I found a round about way of doing this with conditional formatting as well as with formulas in the cells.  I used the Cell Value Contains 'FM' or whatever my various values are, 9 different in all with a different color fill. I then used the formula =IF(COUNTIF(Z1,"FM"),"","") in the specified columns and adjust the "FM" to whatever it needs to be to return the color I want from the conditional formatting. Thanks everyone for the brainstorming. This seems to do the trick.

the FM is italicized because i have * on either side but is not showing in my response. Doing so allows a return for partial matches and not if the cell ONLY has the FM. I can put in FM BH CHIRO in a cell and the column I want the formatted color for FM will still fill.

If you want to be able to change the cells based on the cell's value that's easy with conditional formatting.

Highlight the cells you want to have highlighted based on values.
Then under the "Home" tab, find "Conditional Formatting" and select "New Rule"
You want the option, "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
The rule would simply read the cell (unlocked, so it reads like A1 instead of $A$1) = the text you want. So, =A1="BH" for example and then select "Format" and choose the fill color you want.
Repeat step 4 for the other texts and color you want for the range.


There isn't a excel formula to check the cell color and bring values from that, for that you'd need to check the color code via VBA and then have it populate from there but that's a bit more involved than conditionally formatting.
